# inserting data into a table that has a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working on an assignment and need your help with the following in SQL database:-

I have 3 tables

1. Product
2. LintItem
3. Invoice

LineItem is a bride table and I need to insert data into LineItem but it requires ProductID and InvoiceNumber. 
In my case the Invoice table is emppty and it will be filled from the data that LineItem table passes.

The problem is how can I create an invoice before having the data from the lineItem table?

I am using these table for online shopping cart.

It's really hard for me to explain this problem. Hope you understand it, Thanks!

Comment: How do you insert it, what is the source of your data?

Comment: the problem is I the data that I want to insert into Invoice table will come from LineItem table. for example, ItemPrice*Qantity to get the subtotal etc..

Comment: The data is from the shopping page. If a user clicks add item, then this will be added to the LineItem table and if user checks out, then I will insert the data into the Invoice table.

Comment: Since *...It's really hard for me to explain this problem...* at least [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17767973/edit) your question and add your table schemas, sample data and desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a foreign key constraint forcing the existence of a Invoice record prior to inserting your line item records.  It is hard to say exactly, based on the phrasing of your question but could be something like.

```
--Table variable to hold line items
DECLARE @lineItems TABLE
(
   InvoiceNumber INT,
   Quantity INT
)
```

INSERT INTO @lineitems VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO @lineitems VALUES(1,2)

--ADD INVOICE RECORD FIRST AND SUM Quantities etc....
INSERT INTO Invoice
   SELECT InvoiceNumber,SUM(Quantity)
    FROM @lineItems
    GROUP BY InvoiceNumber

--NOW YOU CAN ADD LINE ITEMS
INSERT INTO LineItems SELECT * FROM @lineItems

This is a pattern you could use if that was your goal.

If you are wanting to insert these LineItems on the fly as the user is clicking Add from the webpage.  I wouldn't use your LineItem SQL table for caching this way.  Without knowing anything about your application it is hard to say but you really should be caching this data in the HTTP session or in the client as (array,json, local storage etc..).  If you were to choose to do this as an SQL table just make a new LineItem without the constraints and then similarly per above you can use that table to insert into your LineItem table.