# MySQL - How to insert into table that has many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship, sql-insert

I have a table of persons. Each person has a property and many persons may have a certain property. So this is a many-to-many relationship. This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  property_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  property varchar(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (property_id)
);

CREATE TABLE has_property (
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  property_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id,property_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons (person_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES properties (property_id)
);
```

Now lets say i want to insert to the database this person:

- firstname:'John'
- lastname:'Doe'
- properties:'property_A','property_B','property_C'

persons

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| person_id | firstname | lastname |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|         1 | John      | Doe      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

properties

```
+-------------+------------+
| property_id |  property  |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 | property_A |
|           2 | property_B |
|           3 | property_C |
+-------------+------------+
```

has_property

```
+-----------+-------------+
| person_id | property_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 |
|         1 |           2 |
|         1 |           3 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

So far the best thing i have thought is to do a regular insert in the persons table:

```
INSERT INTO persons (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('John','Doe');
```

and then do a select to find the id of the person i just inserted

```
SELECT person_id FROM persons WHERE firstname='John' AND lastname='Doe';
```

in order to insert into the other two tables (because i need to know the person_id). 
But i think there must be a better way, isn't it?

Comment: You can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the Id of the last inserted row

Comment: For those that may say this is a duplicate, I have read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767973/inserting-data-into-a-table-that-has-a-many-to-many-relationship but it was vague and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is what i ended up doing. I hope it helps someone.

```
INSERT INTO persons (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('John','Doe');
SET @person_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT IGNORE INTO properties (property) VALUES ('property_A');
SET @property_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO has_property (person_id,property_id) VALUES(@person_id, @property_id);

INSERT IGNORE INTO properties (property) VALUES ('property_B');
SET @property_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO has_property (person_id,property_id) VALUES(@person_id, @property_id);

INSERT IGNORE INTO properties (property) VALUES ('property_C');
SET @property_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO has_property (person_id,property_id) VALUES(@person_id, @property_id);
```

Comment: I know it's been 7yrs but do you remember why you were using `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT` for `properties` table? Any particular reason?

Comment: According to https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/ it means that mysql won't throw an error in case the insert fails. I'm not sure why the insert would fail or why you would want to continue if it did. `SET @property_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` would remain unchanged and would be used in the following ´has_property` inserts