# How to add category to product in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, shopping-cart

I created two tables Category and Products for my shopping cart database. Should I build a third table CategoryProduct and save both the ID's of category and Products in it or have a column in the product table to save the category to it.

I ask because I need to display the products, category wise. Please guide or show me an example.

Comment: Research database relationships.  A  CategoryProduct table would be an example as a many-to-many relationship between Categories and Products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the product belongs to only one category, then you don't need a third table. Just create a column `CategoryId` as a foreign key and references the `CategoryId` from the categories table.

However, if the product belongs to many categories, then you need a third table, something like `CategoryProducts` with columns:

- `Id`: Primary key works as a surrogate key, it has nothing to do with the relations,
- `ProductId` (references the product id column from products table,
- `CategoryId` (references the category id column from categories table.

Comment: Could you please show an example of how to insert a new product with 2 categories to the Products table and store its relationship at the same time. Is it possible to do in 1 single query ?

Comment: @faniva - Check this question and the answer to do it on mySQL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714308/mysql-how-to-insert-into-table-that-has-many-to-many-relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Creat new table with two fileds product_id and category_id this way relation can be maintain properly with cardinality many to many(many prodct related to many category).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if a Product can have more than one Category, if this is the case then you will need the 3rd table to hold id's of both.  If it is one Category per product you can add a Foreign Key to the Product table to hold the category id.

Comment: I thought you could upvote answers to your questions.  Sorry.